# How to use Google Acounts API in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I have a Python based webapp, in wich one, I would like to use Google Accounts to let the users log in. it is simple, let's say my app is on:

> http://myapp.appspot.com/

What I want to do is to "greet" the users with the Google Accounts Auth Screen when they navigate to the app, and only after logged in, let them see the App's interface.

The other way to do it would be adding a static folder, let's say "premium" and in that case, All the users would be able to see app's interface without logging in, but let's say they want to go into:

> http://myapp.appspot.com/premium/whatever.htm

So, in that case, I would like to restrict all the "/premium" URL's to the logged in users...

I understand it's easy to do by just adding this handler into my "app.yaml" file:

```
- url: /premium/.*
  script: premium.py
  login: required
```

But the thing is, I don't understand what does "premium.py" content has to be...

Can you help me with this confusion? Thanks!

Comment: You've already described the answer in your question: use `login: required` on any handler that you want to be login-only. What are you confused about?

Comment: Well, I did that, I added the Example Handler in my app.yaml file, The thing is, I created a static folder called "premium" where I located all the premium content, and if you go to: http://myapp.appspot.com/premium/somepage.html you get access but it never asks for login, even when the "login: required" parameter is there, and if you add it to the static handler of "premium" it throws an error and Never acess to the page, My question is What would be the content of a ".py" script that requires login for users who try to access any "/premium" url? How can I require login for that URL's?

Comment: You probably need to include more of your app.yaml in the question, make sure the order matches your actual file.  You're probably running over the static content with your dynamic handler or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app.yaml solution should work.  But you also asked how to do it in python.  Either will work.  Both is unnecessary.  Here it is:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

class Premium(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if not user:
      this.redirect(users.create_login_url(this.request.uri))
    # Your normal page code here
```

(and I assume you understand the rest, or really you need to read the GAE hello world tutorial)

Clear out your browser cookies!  Especially when you are using the local dev environment.  You might be logged in and not know it!

Comment: How to make it correctly trough the "app.yaml"? what I mentioned above doesn't seem to work :S